# Using ajax function, get info from DB

Tags: php, ajax, json

I need help for getting station list from database and fill the options list.
I have a html file with one button and options list.
I want to fill those options with the list of stations by getting from the database.
My ajax function like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var q = $("#q").val();

$.ajax({

url:'Stations.php',
type:'POST',
data: 'q=' + str, 
dataType: 'json',
success: function( json ) {
    $.each(json, function(i, value) {
        $('#selectSt')
              .append($('<option></option>', {text:value})
              .attr('value', text));
        });
    }
  });
});
```

My Stations.php

```
    function getStationList()
    {
$db = new DBManager();
$mysqli = $db->db_connect();

$query = "SELECT stationId FROM Station";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$list = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $list[] = $row['stationId'];
}

return json_encode($list);
    }
```

My div class.

```
<div class="content" data-role="content" id="content" >
     <div id="car">
        <select name="selectSt" class="span12" id="selectSt" > 
        <option></option>
        <option></option>     /*I want to fill these gaps.
        <option></option>
        </select> 


     </div>
     <div id="cinfo"></div>
    <button onclick="javascript:callCarInfo.call(this,document.getElementById('selectSt').value);">Call     Podcar</button>
 </div>
```

Please tell me what am i missing or what to do?

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what is happening now? Do you receive any errors in your PHP log or Javascript console?

Comment: I'm expecting to see the list of the stations as options.
Nothing happens it is just empty options.
There is no error, i think something is missing or logically wrong

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: unfortunatelly no error, that's why i couldn't see what is wrong

Comment: does the stations.php provide data? does the javascript receive the data?

Comment: stations.php has included database.php and database.php has the database name and tables etc

how can i know js whether receive the data or not

Comment: To see if javascript is getting the data properly, you could simply add `console.log([something from the data])` somewhere.

Comment: javascript does not get any data but it must in this way i think

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your JQuery append isn't quite right. Try this:

```
$('#selectSt').append($('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
```

Comment: does not change anything unfortunatelly, still no error in code